# Make Realloc behave like Calloc

Tags: dynamic, initialization, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, calloc

How can I force Realloc to behave like calloc?
For instance:

I have the following structs:

```
typedef struct bucket0{
    int hashID;
    Registry registry;
}Bucket;

typedef struct table0{
    int tSize;
    int tElements;
    Bucket** content;
}Table;
```

and I have the following code in order to grow the table:

```
 int grow(Table* table){
 Bucket** tempPtr;

 //grow will add 1 to the number available buckets, and double it.
 table->tSize++; //add 1
 table->tSize *= 2; //double element

 if(!table->content){
     //table will be generated for the first time
     table->content = (Bucket**)(calloc(sizeof(Bucket*), table->tSize));
 } else {
     //realloc content
     tempPtr = (Bucket**)realloc(table->content, sizeof(Bucket)*table->tSize);
     if(tempPtr){
         table->content = tempPtr;
         return 0;
     }else{
         return 1000;//table could not grow
     }
   }
 }
```

When I execute it, the table grows properly, and MOST of the "Buckets" in it are initialized as a NULL ptr. However, not all of them are.

How can I make Realloc behave like calloc? in the sense that when it creates new "buckets" they initialize to NULL

Comment: Call ::memset to clear the extra part of the realloced memory?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you shouldn't be relying on `calloc` (or `memset`, for that matter) to set pointers to null. C [doesn't guarantee](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html) that null pointers are represented by all-zero bytes in memory.

Quoting from the [comp.lang.C FAQ question 7.31](http://c-faq.com/malloc/calloc.html):

> Don't rely on `calloc`'s zero fill too much (see below); usually, it's best to initialize data structures yourself, on a field-by-field basis, especially if there are pointer fields.
>
> `calloc`'s zero fill is all-bits-zero, and is therefore guaranteed to yield the value 0 for all integral types (including `'\0'` for character types). But it does *not* guarantee useful null pointer values (see section [5](http://c-faq.com/null/index.html) of this list) or floating-point zero values.

It's safer to initialize the individual structure fields yourself.  You can create a `static const` one as a template, with its `content` initialized to `NULL`, and then `memcpy` it to each element of your dynamically-allocated array.